# Updating page elements with JS efficiently

Tags: javascript, html

I am making a game and using hundreds of lines of

`document.getElementById("ID").innerHTML = someVariable;`

to update everything I calculated with functions. How could I make it better or is this the best method? I can't really use loops for it like

`for (var i = 0; i < IDs.length; i++) {
  document.getElementById("IDs[i]").innerHTML = Variables[i];
}`

beacuse I have so much different variables and diferent ids.

So should I rework everything into arrays and use them or what?

Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Oh yes, and I am at like 1000 lines JS and HTML.

Comment: Why don't you add a class, in addition to an ID?

Comment: Don't use innerHTML, use the DOM API to manipulate the DOM. That's what the browser does anyway every time you give it an html string. The browser also has to first parse the string to determine the DOM elements and their contents. You would definitely speed things up if you just manipulate the DOM with **only** the things you are using.

Comment: How would that work? I can't really imagine it because they need different values.

Answer (score 2):

There are several things that you might do improve performance a little. Unfortunately [jsperf](http://jsperf.com) is down for maintenance at the moment, but I'm not sure that it would help much because the efficiency of DOM manipulations varies so widely between browsers and the particulars of an application.

The first thing I would suggest is a set of "micro efficiencies" which may not even help much but are good practice nonetheless. Keep an array of references to your DOM elements so you don't have to call `getElementById` often. While `getElementById` is very fast, it is still a function call which can be avoided. You might think that the array will take up a lot of memory, but you aren't actually storing the DOM elements in the array but rather storing *pointers* to DOM elements. Also, you can also keep a reference to the `length` of items so that it's not calculated on every loop iteration:

```
const myDivs = [/* populate this array with your DOM elements */];
for (var i = 0, l = IDs.length; i < l; i++) { 
    myDivs[i].innerHTML = Variables[i];
}
```

Another thing which is important is to wait for an animation frame before doing a heavy DOM manipulation. You can read more about [requestAnimationFrame here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).

Finally, you are just going to have to test. As someone suggested in a comment your best bet is to do direct DOM manipulation without using `innerHTML`. The reason for this is because `innerHTML` requires parsing and render tree construction which is expensive. An example of direct DOM manipulation would be... let's say you want to go from this state:

```
<div id="ID[1]">
  <img src="foo.jpg" />
</div>
```

... to this state:

```
<div id="ID[1]">
  <h1>Hello</h1>
  <img src="foo.jpg" />
</div>
```

We just added an H1 - you would write something like this:

```
const h1 = document.createElement('h1');
h1.innerText = 'Hello';
const div = document.getElementById('ID[1]');
div.insertBefore(h1, div.firstChild);
```

But as you can see, this requires you to do a "diff" between the before and after states and calculate the most efficient way to get from one to the other. It just so happens that this is what [ReactJS](https://facebook.github.io/react/) and other Virtual DOM libraries do very efficiently - so you might try out one of those libraries.

If you are against using a library or think that your DOM will fluctuate too much for in-memory diffing to be efficient, then you might try constructing a DOM string and using innerHTML as few times as possible. For example, if your DOM looks like this:

```
<div id="main-container">
  <div id="ID[1]">...</div>
  <div id="ID[2]">...</div>
  <div id="ID[3]">...</div>
  ...
</div>
```

Then try doing something like the following:

```
let html = '';
const container = document.getElementById('main-container');
for (let i = 0, l = IDs.length; i < l; i++) {
  html += `<div id="ID[${i}]">${Variables[i]}</div>`;
}
// you want to set innerHTML as few times as possible
container.innerHTML = html;
```

Comment: Thank you for the nice answer, but I think I missed one important point that everything is done in the HTML like I never create new elements.
I just change the content:
<p>Coins: <span id="coins">0</span><p>
Then I call this with the next setInterval tick:
Coins_num++;
document.getElementById("coins").innerHTML = Coins_num;

Comment: The point is that innerHTML is the absolute most inefficient way to update the DOM. It requires parsing, and then a render tree must be rebuilt. This is very very expensive - I can't overstate this. If you're using innerHTML you are doing it wrong... period. For your last comment, you should grab the text node and set the nodeValue directly: `document.getElementById("coins").firstChild.nodeValue = Coins_num;` (assuming that the "coins" node only has one text node as a child).